# Is there a way to install dependencies like msbuild, .net framework or node.js with the electron app builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an app built with electron, however, when I try to install that app in other computer where there is not installed .net framework or msbuild which are necessary to run the app, it doesn't work. So, is there a way to install that dependencies during the installation?

Comment: Did you get it working? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, with the answer below it was possible.

Answer (score 3):

add a directory 'software' to your project where you put your executables to install.
and in your package.json you can define under your 'build' object 'extraFiles' to put it in your packaged app.

after that you can define a script that should be executed while installation in your nsis area.
here is an example:

```
"build": {
    "win": {...},
    "nsis": {
        // other config stuff,
        "include": "installer.sh"
    },
    "extraFiles": [
        "software"
    ]
}
```

in the `installer.sh` you can define a `customInstall` macro and exec the executables
example:

```
!macro customInstall
    Exec 'cmd command to install executable'
    // or
    ExecWait 'cmd command to install executable'
    // if you need a powershell:
    ExecWait 'Powershell -windowstyle hidden -Command "powershell command"'
    // to get the install path of your app 
    // you can use the global variable $INSTDIR
!macroEnd
```

make shure you have the needed permissions while installation